# How do I auto resize a label's text in WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, devexpress, visual-studio-2015

I put my label inside a two-column grid and set its size to auto and when I run my application, the label's size grows if I maximize it (I'm sure it grows because I've put a background color and the background color also resizes to accommodate the entire two-column grid it's been placed into. My problem is that the label's text itself doesn't grow and stays the same 9pt. Am I missing a property option to set my Label's text to also auto-resize?

I've read tutorials doing this with a viewbox and a textblock and although it works, I've had trouble setting it up in two columns as it resizes weirdly when I run the application despite setting it up right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally did it. What I did was use the Viewbox + Textblock and I've put a border around the viewbox and set its background accordingly and had the textblock's background to none and now it's working as I wanted it to.

The problem I had back then was I didn't know how to put a background color on the viewbox so I tried a remedy wherein I changed the textblock's background but the problem was the textblock has its own size and even if I stretch it, it would only encompass the width of the text and not the whole viewbox.